# Android 3D Object in Layout

Tags: android, intellij-idea, 3d, min3d

I am currently using min3d but i want to have a normal relative layout with an object containing an 3D Model.

Is this possible with min3d?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible in min3d. All you have to do is make your activity extend the Rendereractivity in the min3d library. From that class you can call initscene and updatescene functions where all your loading the obj file and doing the necessary options is possible.